# AngularJS nested ngRepeat on same element

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Is there a way to perform nested loops in an AngularJS view without creating hidden dummy elements?

Something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="gem in activeHero.gems"
        ng-repeat="(key, value) in gem.attributes"
        ng-repeat="attr in value">
            {{attr.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

or this

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="gem in activeHero.gems"
        ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in gem.attributes"
        ng-repeat="attr in value">
            {{attr.text}}
    </li ng-repeat-end 
         ng-repeat-end>
</ul>
```

Neither of these is possible AFAIK.

I basically want my HTML to have a different structure than the JSON it's based on.
How could I achive this? Is there a way to create loops inside a view without an HTML element?

The examples above would loop over a JSON structure like this:

**JSON** (stripped out a lot for clarity)

```
"activeHero" = {
  "gems" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "primary" : [ {
        "text" : "+220 Intelligence"
      } ],
      "secondary" : [ ],
      "passive" : [ ]
    }
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "primary" : [ {
        "text" : "+220 Intelligence"
      } ],
      "secondary" : [ ],
      "passive" : [ ]
    }
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "primary" : [ {
        "text" : "+160 Intelligence"
      } ],
      "secondary" : [ ],
      "passive" : [ ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

(This is an actual JSON response from the Blizzard API for the video game "Diablo 3")

Comment: What do you mean by hidden dummy elements?

Comment: why don't you format your json via javascrip? Don't try with repeater. It would result in lack of performance.

Comment: @pixelbits He means creating elements to add ng-repeat to that don't actually show on the page

Comment: @pixelbits look at this guy:
http://vanderwijk.info/blog/nesting-ng-repeat-start/
He uses additional HTML elements to perform the nested loops which is their only purpose. They're hidden via CSS. Dummy elements for looping (which is stupid IMO)

Comment: @MehmetOtkun that'd be my escape plan if nested looping on the same element isn't possible

Comment: @Sumit if i were you my escape plan would be the other way around. You should keep logic in your view pretty light, instead you should create appropriate viewmodel/model for your view. As mentioned by @_mehmetOtkun transform your model.

Comment: I agree and I'll do that. I'd still like to know if this is possible.

Comment: It is not possible without creating a custom directive or filter. Also There would be more listener more dirty checks etc. that may throw your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try format your json before render;

```
$scope.formattedData = [];
angular.forEach(activeHero.gems, function(value, key){
      var item = {
         //set filed you want
      }
      angular.forEach(value.atrtibutes, function(value2, key2){
               item['propyouwant'] = value2[propyouwant]
               angular.forEach(value2.primary, function(value3, key3){
                      item['propyouwant'] = value3[propyouwant]
                     $scope.formattedData.push(angular.extend({}, item));
               })
      })
})

//now you can render your data without somersould
```

**EDIT**

For increasing performance and avoid to use angular extend;

```
$scope.formattedData = [];
angular.forEach(activeHero.gems, function(value, key){

      angular.forEach(value.atrtibutes, function(value2, key2){
               angular.forEach(value2.primary, function(value3, key3){
                     //start build your item here
                      var item = {
                        prop1: value['prop'],
                        prop2: value2['prop']
                       }
                     //not required extend item;
                     $scope.formattedData.push(item);
               })
      })
})
```